# Is it a UNIT Test or an Integration test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, tdd

I'm working on a school project and I'm researching testing possibilities for Android applications.

On this page: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html Google writes about unit testing.
Is this really a unit test? A Unit test will not integrate all classes and will not test in this context.

So my opinion is, it is not a Unit Test but an Integration Test.
What do you think?

Comment: I get a 404 error on that link.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link...

Comment: that's most certainly an integration test.  If you want to unit test android apps, try robolectric.

Comment: i still get 404 on that link. :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any general consensus on what a unit test is, so it's hard to say.  While some might argue it should be a very small unit of code (e.g. a method), that's pretty limiting, especially considering the fact that when you refactor a passing test, you might put that code into multiple methods or even classes.

[Roy Osherove's definition](http://www.osherove.com/blog/2009/9/28/unit-test-definition-20.html) is as follows:

> A unit test is a fast, in-memory,
> consistent, automated and repeatable
> test of a functional unit-of-work in
> the system.
>
> A unit of work is any functional
> scenario in the system that contains
> logic. it can be as short as a
> function, or it can span multiple
> classes and functions, and it provides
> internal or business value to the
> system under test.

'Fast' and 'in-memory' are, IMO, the main thing separating this from an integration test.  If you go by that, then I think the google tests are indeed unit tests.

Comment: I'd rather emphasize "self-contained" rather than in-memory. A self-contained test does not involve disk access, network, inter-process communication, environment variable, or some other state external to the unit being tested. If it is possible to write a test for the whole program that matches this characteristic, it's a unittest. Being self-contained, consistency, repeatability, and automatibility is implied. In unittest, external states are usually simulated by mocking.

Comment: The examples from Google all need an emulator to test on. This takes much time and they are not self-contained. Some people from Google made it possible to test using the JVM and not de DVM (https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevtesting/notepadsample). So this looks more self-contained... It looks like Google used the wrong word?

Comment: @Lie Ryan - sounds reasonable, although I don't think 'self-contained' is a very clear definition.  At least being 'in-memory' is fairly easy to determine - although you can then use an in-memory DB and pretty much test a whole system using a 'unit' test, which doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: I'd say it is a "unit test". The test requires some environment to run in. All do, as long as the environment is self contained and scriptable why should the details of the environment matter?

Comment: @lans - yeah the need for an emulator does muddy the waters somewhat. Certainly for a whole system, I would define 'unit tests' as the ones I could run without the need for such an environment or other configuration (e.g. using POJOs), while end-to-end style tests involving an emulator I would consider integration tests.  Although Roy's definition doesn't seem to make any such distinction.  Pick whichever definition works for you, I guess!

Comment: @Lie Ryan - I'm writing some tests for a class that takes a bunch of dependencies (a configuration store, a repository etc). Those are all mocked in the test, so there's no testing of real dependencies here, which would suggest it is a unit test; however, the test is also testing the integration of the various dependencies (so verifying that the repository is queried correctly etc), so in that sense, it's an integration test. How would you categorise it?

Comment: @David Keaveny: I'd say it's a unittest, if those dependencies are mocked, then there is no real dependency. It is not an integration test, since it didn't actually test that the "unit" actually integrates to the system, instead it is testing that the "unit" conforms to the interface specification.

Comment: @Lie Ryan - thanks, that's pretty much what I'd concluded. Nice to have some outside confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

A test is not a unit test if:

- It talks to the database
- It communicates across the network
- It touches the file system
- It can't run at the same time as any of your other unit tests
- You have to do special things to your environment (such as editing config files) to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there fellow coders.

I'd like to add that in my experience, it seems best to test behavior of an object, if it does what you need it do to (for your problem domain), whether its one method or more to pass your test.
I know this may sound like simply testing methods, but there is more to it.
A good book to read to help understand this is "Growing Object Oriented Software, Guided by Tests" by Nat Pryce and Steve Freeman.

All in all, good question, and great answers. 
Keep it up.  :-)